# how to compute custom ValidityState

Tags: html, validation

It looks like HTML5 browsers will automatically compute [`ValidityState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ValidityState) for a given `<input>` element, and that it's a read-only object.

What if I want to add custom logic to validate form content? How can I create my own ValidityState object?